# How to find all the JavaScript requests made from my browser when I'm accessing a site

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I want to **scrape** the contents of LinkedIn using requests and bs4 but I'm facing a problem  with the JavaScript that is loading the page after I sign in(I don't get the home page directly), I don't wanna use Selenium

here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Linkedin():
    def __init__(self, url ):
        self.url = url
        self.header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) "
                                 "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"}

    def saveRsulteToHtmlFile(self, nameOfFile=None):
        if nameOfFile == None:
            nameOfFile ="Linkedin_page"
        with open(nameOfFile+".html", "wb") as file:
            file.write(self.response.content)

    def getSingInPage(self):
        self.sess = requests.Session()
        self.response = self.sess.get(self.url, headers=self.header)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.response.content, "html.parser")
        self.csrf = soup.find(attrs={"name" : "loginCsrfParam"})["value"]

    def connecteToMyLinkdin(self):
        self.form_data = {"session_key": "myemail@mail.com",
                     "loginCsrfParam": self.csrf,
                     "session_password": "mypassword"}
        self.url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit"
        self.response = self.sess.post(self.url, headers=self.header, data=self.form_data)


    def getAnyPage(self,url):
        self.response = self.sess.get(url, headers=self.header)




url = "https://www.linkedin.com/"

likedin_page = Linkedin(url)
likedin_page.getSingInPage()
likedin_page.connecteToMyLinkdin() #I'm connected but java script still loading 
likedin_page.getAnyPage("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/")
likedin_page.saveRsulteToHtmlFile()
```

I want help to pass the javascript loads without using Selenium...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it's technically possible to simulate all the calls from Python, at a dynamic page like LinkedIn, I think it will be quite tedious and brittle.

Anyway, you'd open "developer tools" in your browser before you open LinkedIn and see how the traffic looks like. You can filter for the requests from Javascript (in Firefox, the filter is called XHR).

[image: network tab in developer tools]

You would then simulate the necessary/interesting requests in your code. The benefit is the servers usually return structured data to Javascript, such as JSON. Therefore you won't need to do as much HTML parsing.

If you find not progressing very much this way (it really depends on the particular site), then you will probably have to use Selenium or some alternative such as:

- https://robotframework.org/
- https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/ (port of Puppeteer to Python)

Comment: how do I get this requests with python not in a browser

Comment: The same way as you make the requests in your existing code: via `requests.Session`. But you have to replicate what the browser does.

Comment: didn't understand what do you mean. what I expect is to find some automatic methode to retreviw all the java requests; not to declare them manually .

Comment: In that case I think you'll really need something that runs Javascript. Puppeteer, Selenium or similar. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: because slinum is making my program very slow

Comment: Try Puppeteer then. Also running the browser headless (without the real window) may speed things up a bit. As @Adarsh Punj wrote, you may be able to come up with some pure Python solution for current version of LinkedIn. But in general, you can't predict the requests without actually running the Javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

You should send all the XHR and JS requests manually [in the same session which you created during login]. Also, pass all the fields in request headers (copy from the network tools).

```py
self.header_static = {
        'authority': 'static-exp2.licdn.com',
        'method': 'GET',
        'path': '/sc/h/c356usw7zystbud7v7l42pz0s',
        'scheme': 'https',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7,la;q=0.6',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'dnt': '1',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'referer': 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Mobile Safari/537.36'
        }

def postConnectionRequests(self):
        urls = [
        "https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/62mb7ab7wm02esbh500ajmfuz",
        "https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/mpxhij2j03tw91bpplja3u9b",
        "https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/3nq91cp2wacq39jch2hz5p64y",
        "https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/emyc3b18e3q2ntnbncaha2qtp",
        "https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/9b0v30pbbvyf3rt7sbtiasuto",
        "https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/4ntg5zu4sqpdyaz1he02c441c",
        "https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/94cc69wyd1gxdiytujk4d5zm6",
        "https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/ck48xrmh3ctwna0w2y1hos0ln",
        "https://static-exp2.licdn.com/sc/h/c356usw7zystbud7v7l42pz0s",
        ]

        for url in urls:
            self.sess.get(url,headers=self.header_static)
            print("REQUEST SENT TO "+url)
```

I called the `postConnectionRequests()` function after before saving the HTML content, and received the complete page.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this means that I have  to grabe all the requests manually ?.

Comment: If you don't execute Javascript, then in general, yes.

Comment: Unless you find these links in the HTML doc itself, you will have to collect these links manually. Though doing this isn't very lengthy, as there are only ~10 such links. You can go to /jobs/, /in/, etc., and collect these links from the Network tab.

Answer (score 2):

XHR is send by `JavaScript` and Python will not run JavaScript code when it will get page using requests and beautifulsoup. Tools like `Selenium` loads page and runs JavaScript. You can also use `Headless Browsers`.